# virtual box 4.3 installation error in windows 10 technical preview

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-preview

When I try to install oracle virtual box in windows 10 technical preview, it smoothly till it gets to the point where it starts to roll back and then shows something like "Virtualbox ended prematurely".

I have tried running it with Administrative access, but the problem persisted.

Comment: try the Beta of Virtualbox 5: http://dlc-cdn.sun.com/virtualbox/5.0.0_BETA1/

Comment: there is now the Beta2: http://dlc-cdn.sun.com/virtualbox/5.0.0_BETA2 Have you tried the BEta1?

Comment: @magicandre1981 no I haven't tried beta1

Comment: ok, try the beta2 and look what happens.

Comment: It didn't worked too. I got the same message again

Comment: report it in the Virtualbox forums: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=2